# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log| |y_n||$?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, linear-transformations

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 &-1\\
0 & 4 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and let $\{y_n\}$ be three-dimensional number vector
$$
y_1=\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix},y_{n+1}=Ay_n
 $$
then, what is the 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log| |y_n||\quad?$$

**My attempt:**

Since  $$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0\\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But I have no idea what should be the next step.
Can somone help me to solve ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of operator norms?

Comment: @GSofer Unfortunately I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

$$y_1=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$y_2=Ay_1=A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}+A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}=1\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}+3\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$y_{n+1}=1^n\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}+3^n\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Easy to see that
$$\frac{1}{n}\log| |y_{n}||\rightarrow \log3$$

Comment: How did you compute the last step?

Comment: You may directly compute the norm of $y_n$, which is $\sqrt{(3^n+1)^2+(3^n-1)^2}$

Comment: then the limit should be an easy calculus question

Comment: oh I see. Now that makes sense. Thank you